# What is the best and most optimal way to do periodic jobs like sending location data to web server?

Tags: android, performance

I need to periodically (every 5 seconds) send my location info (latitude, longitude) to  web server even if my app is not in foreground, so which is the best way in terms of resource usage and being optimal? is a background service a good choice, i read in documentations that in API level 26 and later, it has some restrictions when application is not running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why down vote? i just want to know the right way of doing that.

Comment: You must read the rules of Stack Overflow and take a tour. It will show you how to properly ask a question and questions which are allowed. Just so you dont get flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid your app to enter sleep (or Doze) mode it should start a foreground service and show a non dismissable notification.

For the timing you can use a Handler + Runnable.

The Handler + Runnable does not necessarily have to be in the Service class, it will be the whole application that will be kept awake, not only the Service.

UPDATED: 
For a period the only 5 seconds the only way I know is to keep the device awake, of course it will affect battery consumption. For longer periods (>15 min) probably AlarmManager will be a better solution with less battery  drain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about resource usage (like battery consuming)? Is this the optimal way?

Comment: I updated my answer